# Text not shwoing in the Scrollview

Tags: android, uiscrollview, chat

I am making an application where i have to implement chat feature. I am having trouble with the chat UI.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:id="@+id/comment_rl"">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/comment_scrollView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

         <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/comment_ll">

         </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/comment_scrollView"
        android:background="#ffffff">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Back"
            android:id="@+id/comment_back_btn"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/comment_editText"
            android:layout_weight="3" />

        <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Send"
        android:id="@+id/comment_send_btn"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[this is the picture of my ui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y7JRX.jpg)

In the image, the message "joool" is getting sent properly and it is being displayed at the screen as i can see it in my database but its actually not showing in the ui its either behind the back button or out of the screen. So i am not sure how to solve this? I am stuck at this for 2 days and cant seem to find a way to keep the text above the edittext.

```
public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
   String comment = (String) dataSnapshot.getValue();
   Log.d("Tag", "comment" + comment);
   LinearLayout.LayoutParams selected_qstn_comment_lp = 
   new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
   selected_qstn_comment_lp.setMargins(10,25,5,5);
   selected_qstn_comment_lp.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
   TextView selected_qstn_comment = 
   new TextView(getApplicationContext());
   selected_qstn_comment.setTextSize(14.0f);
   selected_qstn_comment.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
   selected_qstn_comment.setPadding(10,5,0,0);
   selected_qstn_comment.setText("\n" + comment + "\n");
   selected_qstn_comment.setLayoutParams(selected_qstn_comment_lp);
   ll.addView(selected_qstn_comment);
}
```

This is where i am populating the chat section of the app.

NOTE: The scrollview is actually working as i am able to scroll from top to down. but its actually not wrapping the whole content that's the problem. I suppose its because of the margins i am giving? but i am not sure because it should actually wrap the content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your layout as below:

```
...
<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/comment_scrollView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/my_linear">

         <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/comment_ll">

         </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>

<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:id="@id/my_linear"
        android:background="#ffffff">

...
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Glad to be of help. Minor tip if not already aware: in your layout files, while using `id`, you simply need to use the `@+id/` only the first time you use the widget name. All other time you can simply use `@id/`. Like I did above for your `<LinearLayout>`

Comment: Thank you for the tip i really appreciate it :) will keep that in mind!